# Find unclosed tag in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, tags

I am using MySQL, Java, JSP. If I have an error like below, how do I find the error without manual looking at code? The file is .jsp. Error on web page:

> com.itextpdf.tool.xml.exceptions.RuntimeWorkerException: Invalid
>   nested tag td found, expected closing tag br

```
strBuffer.append("<tr><td colspan=\"2\" ><strong>BlahVariable</strong> 
</td>");
strBuffer.append("<td colspan=\"5\" >");

strBuffer.append("</td></tr><tr>");
strBuffer.append("<td colspan=\"2\" ><strong>BlahVariable</strong></td><td 
colspan=\"5\" >");
if(BlahVariable.equals("Y") ||BlahVariable!=0) 
    strBuffer.append(BlahVariablez);
else
    strBuffer.append("-");
strBuffer.append("</td></tr><tr>");
strBuffer.append("<td colspan=\"2\" ><strong>Blah blah <sup>&diams;</sup> 
</strong></td>");
strBuffer.append("<td colspan=\"5\" >"+ BlahVariable+"</td></tr><tr>");
strBuffer.append("<td colspan=\"2\" ><strong>BlahVariable</strong></td>");
strBuffer.append("<td colspan=\"5\" >");
```

Comment: last `</tr>` is missing.

Comment: Um, manually looking at code is 90% of what we _do_ in this business.  No way around it (at least _this_ time).

Answer (score 0):

- Can create a [Custom Exception of java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-32-user-defined-custom-exception-in-java/) for the same.
- Thus errors can be caught easily.
- Also to avoid such errors can previously write the code in html/jsp file itself and then Ctrl+C Ctrl+V.